# Cannot use * with WHERE in query in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I used the GridDB Node Js connector and ran the query "Select * WHERE salary = 50000." This SQL query is correct, but because GridDB uses TQL, we cannot perform it. I tried it on GridDB anyways and received the following error:

```
[Error code]: 150013

[Description] (* is used in the WHERE condition)

[Format] Error description below

* cannot be used in the WHERE condition
```

So how would I perform this query in TQL?